# How to handle dependency when using another pen as resource in CodePen?

Tags: javascript, css

In CodePen, I created a pen "LIB" as a external resource for pen "DEMO" to include.

The problem is that, pen "LIB" requires several external resources (say jQuery), which are not automatically included into pen "DEMO".

I have to repeat all the external resources in pen "LIB".

Is there a easy way to relieve this pain?